# cant print the arrays

Tags: java, arrays, printing

i want to call the arrays to the method and add it in a catalog but i cant print it as it shows [[Ljava.lang.String;@7ad041f3, [Ljava.lang.String;@251a69d7, [Ljava.lang.String;@7344699f] when i print it. i think its cause of the way i called the attribute title,author and genre but i dont know how to call.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Card{
    String title[] = {"Hairy potter","Perck Jackson","The promised Neverland","Goosebump"};
    String author[] = {"j.k.Rowling","Rick Riordan","Kaiu Shirai","R.L.Stine"};
    String genre[] = {"Fantasy Fiction","Adventure","Dark fantasy","Horror fiction"};
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Card obj = new Card();
        String[] title1,author1,genre1;
        title1 = obj.title;
        author1 = obj.author;
        genre1 = obj.genre;
        String[][] catalog = new String[3][4];
        for (int i = 0 ; i<4;i++){
            catalog[0][i] =title1[i];
            catalog[1][i] =author1[i];
            catalog[2][i]= genre1[i]; 
        }
        System.out.println((catalog[0]));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(catalog));
    }
}
```

Edit:
i had to use Arrays.deepToString(catalog)

Answer (score 0):

When you try to print catalog[0], it returns you the data type. Here, that is java.lang.String.

What you're looking for is:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(catalog));
```

This will print the contents.

Comment: please vote this message.